# managing jenkins credentials by users/roles

Tags: jenkins

I am currently trying to find a way to allow only certain users to use stored credentials in jenkins. I have not found a way to do this using the credential plugin. I am using the role based Access plugin as well.

is there a way to create credential domains that can only be accessed by allowed users?

how can a user use the credentials that they provide in their own "user profile" configuration area?

Is this possible ? or is there another plugin that can do this.

Comment: Most times you can provide the credentials in the individual job configuration. But I am interested in a global solution. Most times we manage the credentials for our users which is not the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Not to miss an obvious answer - undocumented, but easy enough to figure out.
It only works for ssh/sftp access.

- Edit a job.
- Mark it "parameterized".
- Add a parameter

  - type: credential
  - named `my-ssh-private-key`
- Mark "SSH agent"

  - parameterized credential =  `${my-ssh-private-key}`
- Enter `ssh my_host "echo Hello world"` as job's batch script action

Try to build the job. You would be asked to choose credentials, and here, lo and behold, you can pick also your **private credentials** amongst the global ones. But other users can only run this job if they have their own authorized ssh private key (with public part included in the remote `authorized_keys`).

If you have "host key verification" error, just go to jenkins shell to fix:

```
su - jenkins
ssh my_host # confirm the host key to be saved into your known_hosts
tail ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```